# Font changes when using mathbf in math mode with unicode-math package

Tags: unicode-math

I am using `fontspec` and the `unicode-math` packages to load the Libertinus Serif and Libertinus Math fonts respectively. However, when I use the `\mathbf` command in math mode, the font inexplicably changes to Latin Modern. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,realscripts}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily\lmr{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
$1234567890$ \textbf{1234567890} $\mathbf{1234567890}$ \textbf{\lmr 1234567890}
\end{document}
```

How do I get the **bold** version of Libertinus Serif using `\mathbf`?

**EDIT** 
Adding the following does not help either:

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{Libertinus Serif}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the font for `\mathbf` in the usual way, also you can use `\symbf` which rather than use a separate font, uses the bold alphabet in the upper plane 1 math alphabet block in the regular math font. (Older versions of `uniocde-math` defined `\mathbf` to use this range)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,realscripts}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily\lmr{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{Libertinus Serif}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}
\begin{document}
$1234567890$ \textbf{1234567890} $\mathbf{1234567890} \symbf{123456789}$ \textbf{\lmr 1234567890}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the option to use `\symbf` as I dont like to change the default definitions. `@Herbert's` solution seems clean too. Unfortunately my upvote won't show due to poor reputation.

Comment: Don't worry, mine will

Answer (score 1):

Let `unicode-math` load all font related packages packages:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily\lmr{Latin Modern Roman}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
    $1234567890$ \textbf{1234567890} $\mathbf{1234567890}$ \textbf{\lmr 1234567890}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a clean solution. Apparently my upvote wont show as I have poor reputation. Can you briefly explain why this solution works?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work"  is _not_ a useful comment. It works for me!

Comment: When I make it, XeLaTeX is substituting CMBX10 for the \mathbf{}     Retrieving info from pages 1-1...
Fonts (1):
 1 (3 0 R): Type1 'EOGXUB+CMBX10' (4 0 R)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an alternative solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfontface\mathbf{Libertinus Serif Semibold}
\newfontfamily\lmr{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
$1234567890G$ \textbf{1234567890G} $\mathbf{1234567890G}$ \textbf{\lmr 1234567890G}
```

\end{document}